# Draw Custom Route using Android Google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google maps Direction by default gave us a route that has a mini distance, but for my case I want to draw a custom route is this possible with android google maps api v2 ?
example :
[image]

How can I do that in android google maps api v2 ?

**P.S :** 
I already know how to draw route beetween two point but not a custom one just fellowing google directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant waypoint.

Look for waypoint in this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Between your start and end point,  you can set up to 8 waypoint for free which will draw a route that connect all of these point between start to finish

If its other kind of custom route you talk about then , I guess you will ended up having to find each route between 2 point at a time

Comment: yes it's exactly the waypoint. So it's support only 8 waypoint I see thank you for your answer !

Comment: 8 waypoints its free, and you can pay to upgrade. Its stated in the same link above,  look for the words 'Usage Limits'

Comment: @H-Ideas have u got the solution?, can u pls provide the sample for draw the custom routes as u did it.